# Ionic odd behaviour with state transitions inside drawer side menu content area

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm designing an application for mobile phones using cordova. I've made some good progress where I can transition between state to state inside my side menu content while still having drawer working. The way I have the interface designed is to have the side drawer and header bar be loaded once and the side menu content be the area of state transitions. I could not get my content to display below the header bar so I padded it down. However the issue is when I push things down the state transition animation pads also, oddly I tested menu-close directive in the tag, so it seems like the padded area is holding previous state of side menu content. I would prefer not use use menu-close so I don't reset the history stack on my states.

```
<ion-side-menus  animation="no-animation" enable-menu-with-back-views ="true" >
<!--Ion Side Menu Content Houses the content for the main page-->
<ion-side-menu-content style="padding-top:45px">


<div menu-close style="padding-top:59px" >
<ion-nav-view > --Here
</ion-nav-view>    
</div>


 <ion-header-bar class ="bar-balanced">
 <div class ="buttons">
     <button class ="button icon button-clear ion-navicon-round" ng-click="openDrawer()"></button>
    </div>
    <h1 class="title" style="text-align: center">Medroid</h1>
    <div class="buttons widget-container content-area horiz-area  wrapping-col" > 
    <button class ="button" ng-click="openPopover($event)" ng-controller = "notificationPopoverCtrl">
        <i class ="icon button-dark ion-ios-bell"></i></button>
        <button class ="button" ng-click="openPopover($event)" ng-controller ="InboxPopoverCtrl"><i class ="icon button-dark ion-email"></i> </button> 
         <button class ="button" ng-click="changeStatus()"><i class     ="icon ion-ios-circle-filled {{statuscolor}}"></i>{{docstatus}}</button> 
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>
</ion-side-menu-content>
<!--Ion Side menu drawer content-->
<ion-side-menu side ="left">
<ion-header-bar class ="bar-positive">
<h1 class="title" style="text-align: center" >Menu</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
</ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Here is a link to my plunker where I've implemented this.
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WuPJCoo2FQV1bkR0gvLj?p=preview)

You're help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by removing the top padding and replace it with margin top.

```
<ion-nav-view style ="margin-top:43px">
```